# MySQL error: Cannot add foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-error-1064

There always be the error:**"Cannot add foreign key constraint"** when I create **my last table**.

---

System: Mac OS X 10.9
DB    : MySQL 5.6.14
DBM   : Sequel Pro

---

```
CREATE TABLE users (
uid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
uname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
uemail VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ucity VARCHAR(20),
upassw VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE songs(
sid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
sname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
srldate DATE NOT NULL
);



CREATE TABLE albums (
albid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
albname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
albrldate DATE NOT NULL,
albrltime TIME NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE artists (
aid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
aname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE genres (
gid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
gname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE playlists (
uid INT NOT NULL,
sid INT NOT NULL,
plname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
plmdate DATE NOT NULL,
plmtime TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(uid, sid, plname, plmdate, plmtime),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
FOREIGN KEY(sid) REFERENCES songs(sid)
);

CREATE TABLE u_like_a (
aid INT NOT NULL,
uid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(aid, uid),
FOREIGN KEY(aid) REFERENCES artists(aid),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE be_fan (
aid INT NOT NULL,
uid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(aid, uid),
FOREIGN KEY(aid) REFERENCES artists(aid),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE follow (
uid INT NOT NULL,
to_uid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(uid, to_uid),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
FOREIGN KEY(to_uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE u_like_g (
gid INT NOT NULL,
uid INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(gid, uid),
FOREIGN KEY(gid) REFERENCES genres(gid),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE u_share_pl(
uid INT NOT NULL,
from_uid INT NOT NULL,
plname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
plmdate DATE NOT NULL,
plmtime TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(uid, from_uid, plname, plmdate, plmtime),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
FOREIGN KEY(from_uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
FOREIGN KEY(plname) REFERENCES playlists(plname),
FOREIGN KEY(plmdate) REFERENCES playlists(plmdate),
FOREIGN KEY(plmtime) REFERENCES playlists(plmtime)
); #####--->  This is the last table.
```

ERROR comes from here. I really don't why.
I have check the type for all attributes. The type and name of attributes have no problem.
But the mysql always say **"Cannot add foreign key constraint"**

Comment: Which table engine are you using? MyISAM does not support foreign keys.

Comment: @ioseph: but MyISAM would never thrown an error that it doesn't support foreign keys or that it can't create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is you reference wrong forgien `REFERENCES users(from_uid)` in last table.

```
FOREIGN KEY(from_uid) REFERENCES users(from_uid)
```

`from_uid` not belong to `users`

This should be

```
FOREIGN KEY(from_uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
```

your `playLists table` has primary key combination of four columns, so you should supply all these four columns as forieng key in `u_share_pl table`.

Another composite key as a reference should be a single constraint like

```
FOREIGN KEY(from_uid,sid,plname,plmdate,plmtime) REFERENCES playlists(uid,sid,plname,plmdate,plmtime)
```

Your last table Create should be:

```
CREATE TABLE u_share_pl(
uid INT NOT NULL,
from_uid INT NOT NULL,
sid INT NOT NULL,
plname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
plmdate DATE NOT NULL,
plmtime TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(uid, from_uid, plname, plmdate, plmtime),
FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
FOREIGN KEY(from_uid,sid,plname,plmdate,plmtime) REFERENCES playlists(uid,sid,plname,plmdate,plmtime)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I use "FOREIGN KEY(from_uid) REFERENCES users(hid)", it also has the same error "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Comment: perhaps it is typing error, this is users(uid). if not please see other foriegn key like that issues of column names

Comment: This morning, I checked all tables' attributes again. But I really think there has been no mistake. But the error is still there.

Comment: I use "DBM: Sequel Pro". Is it possible that the problem comes from the DBM?

Comment: One minute ago, I drop the database, and use these SQL commands to create tables under the terminal. But the error is same. It looks there is really something wrong in my SQL commands, but I really can not find it out. I have try my best on this problem about 5 hours. I am really upset.

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you so much, you saved me.... I greatly appreciate your help. But the problem comes from the uid and sid from the playlists. That is really weird.