# Mysql constraint cannot add

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in mysql code. Not allow me to import sql file and give me this error " #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint  "

I have no ideea what to do. I searched here, i tried some examples like this: [MySQL error: Cannot add foreign key constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087711/mysql-error-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint) but no succes.

Comment: Why did you removed all the SQL code from your question?  Now this question & answer is useless as it makes no sense.

Comment: it's code from my license... i dont want to be acused of plagiarism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use all of the primary key columns on your FK references.

```
FOREIGN KEY (`an`)
REFERENCES `studenti` (`an`)
```

should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (`idstud`, `an`)
REFERENCES `studenti` (`idstud`,`an`)
```

Of course, then you need to add `idstud` to your `teste` table.